# Client IP Address from Request Header in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ip-address, request-headers

Can I access the IP address of the client from request header?If yes,how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
visitor_ip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
```